# How do I insert into a VARBINARY column using SQLAlchemy's to_sql?

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am reading some varbinary data from SQL Server into a Pandas Dataframe, as shown below.

```
sql = pd.read_sql_query(
'''
  SELECT [VarBinaryData]
  FROM [dbo].[Source]
''', engine)
df = pd.DataFrame(sql)
```

When outputting the DataFrame, the data looks like this.

```
    VarBinaryData
0   b'\x00F\xf4\x8a]L\xdf\xf3\xc1q\xf1XmS\xd9\\'
```

I then want to insert this data into a new table, as shown below.

```
df.to_sql(
    'Target',
    engine,
    schema = 'dbo',
    if_exists = 'append',
    chunksize = 250000,
    index = False,
)
```

However this produces the following error:

> ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', '[42000]
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Implicit
> conversion from data type varchar to varbinary is not allowed. Use the
> CONVERT function to run this query. (257) (SQLExecute)')

Looking at the error in more detail, it is trying to do this.

```
[SQL: INSERT INTO [dbo].[Target] ([VarBinaryData]) VALUES (?)]
[parameters: ((bytearray(b'\xdf\xcdOD*!\xa6\x95\xfe\xc8Se\xcb\xaf\x97\x14')))]
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: What data type is it in Python? It should be a byte array but appears to be a string.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning using df.info() it's showing as an object

Comment: Can you provide a few samples of actual data?

Comment: What do you get from `SELECT DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Source' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'VarBinaryData'` …?

Comment: @GordThompson varbinary

Comment: @JasonCook Added above

Comment: pandas can definitely round-trip `varbinary` data, as illustrated by [this code](https://pastebin.com/Y7NhgVRH). There is something about your particular situation that is misleading you.

Comment: any solutions to this issue, I'm having the same problem...